# gdb not loading symbols when running standalone shared library

Tags: c, linux, gdb, shared-libraries

I have a PIC shared library which also has a main function

```
#include <dtest2.h>
#include <stdio.h>
extern const char elf_interpreter[] __attribute__((section(".interp"))) = "/lib/ld-linux.so.2";

int dtestfunc1(int x,int y) {
  int i=0;
  int sum = 0;
  for(i=0;i<=x;i++) {
    sum+=y;
    sum+=dtestfunc2(x,y);

  }
  return sum;
}

int main (int argc, char const* argv[])
{
  printf("starting sharedlib main\n");
  int val = dtestfunc1(4,5);
  printf("val = %d\n",val);
  _exit(0);
}
```

This library is linked to another shared library `libdtest2` which has the implementation of `dtestfunc2` called from `dtestfunc1`.

If i run gdb directly on dtestfunc1 using

```
gdb libdtest1.so
```

the symbols for libdtest2.so are not loaded by gdb. I cannot step into `dtestfunc1` because of this and if i press s, the function just executes and gets out.

If i create a driver program which calls dlopen on the shared library, gdb loads the symbols properly after dlopen is executed and everything works fine.

1. Why is gdb behaving differently in both these cases?
2. How can i manually point gdb to the shared library if i am running gdb directly on the shared library?

Note: This is a toy example that mirrors my problem for a much larger shared library. All my binaries and libraries are compiled with the -ggdb3 flag.

Edit: My shared library is runnable. I added the proper interpreter path using the extern definition in the source code. I compiled it with `gcc -ggdb3 -O0 -shared -Wl,-soname,libdtest1.so.1 -ldtest2 -L/usr/lib -Wl,-e,main -o libdtest1.so.1.0 dtest1.o`.
I can run it and it executes perfectly.Running the shared library is not the issue here.

Comment: My gdb is rusty, but is it the `file` command that would manually do it (question #2).  If so, you could use a `.gdbinit` file to make it easy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why is gdb behaving differently in both these cases?

Because you didn't build `libdtest1.so` correctly for GDB to work with it.

In particular, your `libdtest1.so` is lacking `DT_DEBUG` entry in its dynamic section, which you can confirm like so:

```
readelf -d libdtest1.so | grep DEBUG
```

You should see nothing. In a correctly built runnable `libdtest1.so` (which you can build using `-pie` flag), the output should look like this:

```
 0x00000015 (DEBUG)                      0x0
```

The runtime loader updates `DT_DEBUG` to point to its `r_debug` structure, which then allows GDB to find other loaded shared libraries. Without `DT_DEBUG`, GDB can't find them.

*Update:*

> After adding the pie flag my build command is `gcc -ggdb3 -O0 -pie -shared -Wl,-soname,libdtest1.so.1 -ldtest2 -L/usr/lib -Wl,-e,main -o libdtest1.so.1.0 dtest1.c -I.` The DEBUG section is still missing

Terminology: it's not a `DEBUG` section. It's a `DT_DEBUG` entry in the `.dynamic` section.

It is still missing because `-shared` overrides `-pie`. Remove `-shared` from the link line.

You would also not need `-Wl,-e,main`, nor would you need to specify the `.interp` -- GCC will do that for you.

The correct link command:

```
gcc -ggdb3 -O0 -pie -rdynamic dtest1.c -I. -Wl,-soname,libdtest1.so.1 \
  -L/usr/lib -ldtest2 -o libdtest1.so.1.0
```

(Order of sources and libraries on the link line matters, yours is wrong.)

Added bonus: your main will receive correct `argc` and `argv[]`, instead of bogus values you are getting now.

Comment: I have made sure that my library is runnable. I can run it and it does not crash. i compiled it with `gcc -ggdb3 -O0 -shared -Wl,-soname,libdtest1.so.1 -ldtest2 -L/usr/lib -Wl,-e,main -o libdtest1.so.1.0 dtest1.o`. As a side note, why would i ask a question on why gdb not stepping into a function if it was crashing immediately when i was running the program?

Comment: @MIkhail I've updated the answer. "why would i ask a question..." I don't know. Why would you ask a question and omit essential details needed to answer it (the build command)?

Comment: I understood that . My apologies.

Comment: After adding the pie flag my build command is `gcc -ggdb3 -O0  -pie -shared -Wl,-soname,libdtest1.so.1 -ldtest2 -L/usr/lib -Wl,-e,main -o libdtest1.so.1.0 dtest1.c -I. `. The DEBUG section is still missing. Any idea why its still missing?

Comment: Thank you. The so has the DT_DEBUG section now :) :). But i cannot link the shared library with other binaries now. It gives `undefined reference to dtestfunc1` error when i link it with `-ldtest1` flag.

Comment: @MIkhail Ahh, you also need `-rdynamic` flag to force exporting all symbols from `libdtest1.so`. Sorry about that.

Comment: That did it! You have no idea how much grateful i am :) I will update the link command with -rdynamic. edit: oh. it was already updated. :) farewell

Answer (score 0):

the easy fix.... recompile the library with (for gcc) the parameter '-ggdb' Then it will have all the symbols available to gdb.

Comment: all binaries are compiled with -ggdb

Comment: That is a completely bogus answer.